# Why is my program terminating after it takes 3 inputs?

Tags: java

This program is an attempt at making a similar game to Battleships on the command line. If my program takes 3 inputs that are "HITS" it terminates. Why is this? My suspicion is that there is something wrong with my logic in the if/else statements.

The reason I have 3 lists is because I want to let the user know that they have hit 3 consecutive numbers and that they have sunk a ship in the game. Also, I am aware of the potential problem that can occur when the random method generates the same number in more than one list.

Apologies if the code is not written very nicely. I am still a beginner.

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static int numOfHits = 0;
public static int numOfGuesses = 0;
public static int userInput;
public static int number;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game a = new Game();
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> hitlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    int temp = a.numGenerator();
    list.add(temp);
    list.add(temp+ 1);
    list.add(temp + 2);

    int temp2 = a.numGenerator();
    list2.add(temp2);
    list2.add(temp2 + 1);
    list2.add(temp2 + 2);

    int temp3 = a.numGenerator();
    list3.add(temp3);
    list3.add(temp3 + 1);
    list3.add(temp3 + 2);

    System.out.println(list + " " + list2 + " " + list3);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to BattleShips! In this version; the game is on a long 30 cell row and there are 3 different sub rows to kill. Input your guesses.");

    while(!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That is not an integer. Please try again.");
        input.next();
    }




    while(list.isEmpty() == false && list2.isEmpty() == false && list3.isEmpty() == false) {



        while(!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("That is not an integer or the number is too large to be stored as an integer. Please try again.");
            input.next();
        }
        userInput = input.nextInt();

        while(hitlist.contains(userInput)) {
            System.out.println("You have already hit that one! Try again.");
            userInput = input.nextInt();

        }

        while(true) {
        if(list.contains(userInput)) {

            numOfGuesses++;
            numOfHits++;
            int index = list.indexOf(userInput);
            hitlist.add(userInput);
            list.remove(index);
            System.out.println("HIT!");
            userInput = -100;
            break;

        }



        if(list2.contains(userInput) && !list.contains(userInput)) {

            numOfGuesses++;
            numOfHits++;
            int index = list2.indexOf(userInput);
            hitlist.add(userInput);
            list2.remove(index);
            System.out.println("HIT!");
            break;
        }



        if(list3.contains(userInput)) {

            numOfGuesses++;
            numOfHits++;
            int index = list2.indexOf(userInput);
            hitlist.add(userInput);
            list3.remove(index);
            System.out.println("HIT!");
            break;
        }

        else {
            numOfGuesses++;
            System.out.println("MISS!");
        }
        }

        if(numOfHits == 9) {

        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have beaten the game.");
        System.out.println("You took " + numOfGuesses + " guesses");
        System.exit(0);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

**Game**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Game {


private double randomNumber;


public int numGenerator() {

    randomNumber =  Math.random() * 30 + 1;
    return (int) randomNumber;

 }
}
```

**The bug**

I do not get a compiler error. It is a logic error. Here is an example:

```
 [15, 16, 17] [8, 9, 10] [28, 29, 30] // NUMBERS GENERATED FROM MATH.RANDOM 
 Welcome to BattleShips! In this version; the game is on a long 30 cell       row and there are 3 different sub rows to kill. Input your guesses.
  15
  HIT!
  15
  You have already hit that one! Try again.
  16
  HIT!
  17
  HIT!
  //AFTER THIS LINE IT TERMINATES. I WANT THE USER TO KEEP MAKING GUESSES UNTIL 9 NUMBERS ARE HIT.
```

Comment: What line and what error do you get?

Comment: @anaxin I shall edit the post now

Comment: @StephenPeterWisniewski What are the three lists? What do you intend to store in them?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I have stored random numbers within the list. The user must guess all of the numbers in all 3 lists to win the game.

Comment: put this in a debugger and trace the logic flow.

Comment: @arcy I have not learnt how to use a debugger, but I will try.

Comment: int index = list2.indexOf(userInput); you have that in the list3 if section

Comment: consider condition in your main loop `while(list.isEmpty() == false && list2.isEmpty() == false && list3.isEmpty() == false)`  if one of your list will be empty, then whole condition will be false.  and loop will stop. and that what happened when you tried to run it. what you need to do is change your condition

Comment: @user902383 and anaxin I cannot believe it was such a simple error. Thank you two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your while condition:

```
while(list.isEmpty() == false && list2.isEmpty() == false && list3.isEmpty() == false)
```

It checks till any one of the lists is not empty.

Change it to:

```
while(list.isEmpty() == false || list2.isEmpty() == false || list3.isEmpty() == false) {
```

This will check till all of the lists are not empty.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was such a simple mistake